# Showing that a function is $\mu$-integrable

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space, that is complete. Suppose that $(f_n)$ is a sequence of measurable functions, $f_n:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and that the series $F(x) = \Sigma_{n\in \mathbb{N}} f_n(x)$ converges $\mu$-almost everywhere.

Also suppose that there exists a non-negative $\mu$-summable function, $g$ such that $|F(x)|\leq g(x)$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

I am trying to show that $F$ is $\mu$-integrable. But I am not sure how to do this. I know that $F$ is $\mu$-summable almost everywhere and hence $\mu$-integrable almost everywhere. Does this imply that $F$ is $\mu$ integrable everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

How do you mean $\mu$-integrable a.e.? Integrability is not a pointwise condition; it is not something that can be satisfied a.e. If $F$ is bounded a.e. by an integrable function $g$, then $F$ is integrable and indeed $$\int_X \lvert F \rvert d\mu \le \int_X g d\mu$$

Answer (score 0):

Since you suppose $F$ is the a.e. limit of a sequence of measurable functions, it is measurable as well. The integral for a measurable function $F$ exists if and only if $\int F^+ d\mu < \infty$ or $\int F^- d\mu < \infty$. Since you also assume $|F(x)| < g(x)$ for some dominating function $g$ and since $g$ is summable, $ \int |F|d\mu= \int F^+d\mu + \int F^- d\mu < \int{g}d\mu < \infty$ . So  both terms are bounded and the integral exists. Concerning your other question with not necesserily positive $f$: You can apply the theorem of dominated convergence ( see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)) with the dominating function $g$.

Comment: What "other question" are you referring to? I don't think there is any use of DCT here; all that is being used is the fact that $\lvert F \rvert \le g$ a.e. implies that $$\int_X \lvert F \rvert d\mu \le \int_X g \,d\mu.$$

Comment: OP  just edited the post, probably before you  saw it. when I wrote the answer, OPs question also contained another task he just deleted. As the question is stated now, your argument is completely satisfying

Comment: Gotcha, my mistake.